# Crates with weighed random percents

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

I am working on a Spigot / Bukkit 1.8 plugin and am trying to add crates with random weighed items.

For example Diamond, 10%; Gold, 30%; Redstone, 50%;

I tried holding items in a list of CrateItem which is the following class

```
private ItemStack item;
private double chance;

public CrateItem(ItemStack item, double chance) {
    this.item = item;
    this.chance = chance;
}

public ItemStack getItem() {
    return item;
}

public double getChance() {
    return chance;
}
```

I then plan to cycle through the items but I don't know the best way to make weighed part count and not be fully random.

Comment: Think of dice. Role a D10, one is a diamond; 2,3 or 4 is gold; 5-10 is a red stone.

Comment: This sounds good but how do I handle it if its like 20% 20% 40% 50% 60% 10% since it overloads 100%

Comment: The chance of mutually exclusive outcomes to one choice cannot add up to more than 100%. But if they’re weights instead of chances, than you first calculate the total, then roll a random number from 1 to total, and then you loop through the weights - if. The remaining roll is less than the weight, then thats the outcome. If not, you subtract the weight from the remaining roll and Continue the loop.

Comment: So lets say I have 50% 20% and 60% for generating I could add all (in my case 50+20+60) then random int from 1 to total if its 1-50 case 1 if 50-70 case 2 if 70-120 case 3. like that?

Answer (score 1):

This is pure theory and I am not experienced with designing drop tables; but, what if you loop through each item and do a true-false check with their drop chance as a percentage. You can repeat the one until only 1 item rolls true (assuming the crate only drops a single item)

To elaborate, you would...

1. Loop through each item and, using their drop chance, generate a true/false value indicating if could drop.
2. If the true/false value is false, remove the item from this crate's drops.
3. If the true/false value is true, keep the item in this crate's drops.
4. Repeat steps 1-3 until there is only 1 item left.
5. The remaining item will be the item that the crate drops.

If your crate is going to drop multiple items, for example 3 drops. You can do the entire process 3 times.

Do be warned, this may cause performance issues if your crate has a lot drops, and/or there is a lot of items to loop through.